# setting a double qouted values in an input/textarea field html

Tags: html

I have a module **"edit info"**. Information to be edited will be displayed in each corresponding fields. However, there are some data fetched from the database which are double quouted and aren't displayed. What is the solution for this?

```
<input class="form-control" name="description" type="text" value="<?php echo $item[0]->desc;?>" required>
```

Comment: Try to add ur code.

Comment: @SESN, i have added my sample code..

Comment: wrap value in single quotes. if your echo is outputting double quotes it's screwing up the element (and it will do it if there are single quotes in there with my solution) You should be HTML encoding your data before saving it to the database then decoding it when outputting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the htmlentities() method:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($item[0] -> desc;)?>
```

That should change `"` to `&quot`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `echo stripslashes($item[0]->desc);` before form element whether u r fetching from the database. There is no problem with code.